# How to call comparison operators from list

Tags: python, list, comparison, operators

Hi I want to install some kind of adjustable comparer where an element from a list **a** is compared to an element of a list **Values** with an operator which is read from a list **Operators**

```
a = [1,2,3,4] # This should be variable
Val = [0.5,1,10,7] # This should have the same length as a
Op = ['<','>','<>','<']

for i in range(len(a)):
    print(a[i]Op[i]Val[i])
```

Comment: Ok, so you're asking us to write it for you? You've not shown any attempt to implement this.

Comment: and you have unbalanced brackets...

Comment: Have you taken a look at [`eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval)?

Comment: @Scratch'N'Purr have you taken a look at [eval really is dangerous](https://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html)?

Comment: @roganjosh I understand the risks of eval, but his lists don't include any dangerous values or variables.

Comment: @Scratch'N'Purr sure, but a) this could be a contrived example, we don't know where those values actually come from in the real program and b) this post may come up in a search from any person solving any problem in future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `eval` even in some situation it is unstable, but if only consider your case , it work as expected and better solution is  `sympy`

```
a = [1,2,3,4] # This should be variable
Val = [0.5,1,10,7] # This should have the same length as a
Op = ['<','>','!=','<']

for i in range(len(a)):
    parse_expr(str(a[i])+Op[i]+str(Val[i]))# or change to eval(str(a[i])+Op[i]+str(Val[i]))

False
True
True
True
```

Comment: I'm really surprised you suggested `eval` here rather than mapping the operations to the `operator` module or suggesting `sympy` or.... literally anything but eval

Comment: @roganjosh I notice that too, just need some time to find out what I used before

Answer (score 4):

Instead of comparison symbols, use the function from [operators](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#module-operator).

May be this can help!

```
from operator import lt, gt, ne, le,eq
a = [1,2,3,4] # This should be variable
val = [0.5,1,10,7] # This should have the same length as a
operation = {'<': lt, '>': gt, '<>': ne, '=': eq}


op = ['<','>','<>','<']

for i,o,j in zip(a,op,val):
    print(operation[o](i,j))

False
True
True
True
```

Comment: That is certainly the best way to do it. It could also work with the original `['<','>','<>','<']` as input, with a simple mapping `{'<': lt, '>': gt, '<>': ne, '=': eq}`

Comment: Thanks. Updated my solution.

Answer (score 1):

Seems that you need programmatic way to call comparison operators, [`operator`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html) module will do the work. Either construct list of operator functions or make signs to operator mapping via `dict`

Answer (score 0):

```
a = [1,2,3,4] # This should be variable
b = [0.5,1,10,7] # This should have the same length as a
c = ['<','>','<>','<']
```

use

```
for i in range(len(a)):
    eval(str(a[i])+b[i]+str(c[i]))
```